# Unable to impot appscript python module

Tags: python, pip

I run the following:

```
sh# python3 -m pip install appscript
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: appscript in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/appscript-1.1.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg (1.1.0)
```

Then I run

```
sh# python3
...
>>> import appscript
```

And get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appscript'
```

Answer (score -1):

try uninstalling

```
pip uninstall appscript
```

and reinstalling

```
pip install appscript
```

Also try changing your code, I ran a test in a venv virtual environment with below import and was successful.

```
from appscript import *
```

instead of

```
import appscript
```

Comment: I tried in a virtual environment and `from appscript import *` worked for me.  Is there any way that you installed globally and are working in a virtual environment or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but may depend on the virtual environment you are using (venv, pipenv, conda, etc)

Comment: Agreed, i shouldve been more specific.  I used venv.  `python -m venv env`  `env\Scripts\activate.bat`

Comment: You can set `--system-site-packages` option during venv creation, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). This will be enough to get access to installed in your system python packages. But this don't prevent you from install specific packages or package version to the environment and have it locally without allowing it in the rest os the system.

Comment: While in a virtual environment it is usually best to only install the packages that are needed which is one of the main purposes of a virtual environment.